# user contacts - android

Tags: java, android, listactivity

The class that displays a list of user contacts.

The problem is that it displays all contacts, including those who do not have a phone number.

I would not add the item, if no number. Due to lack of experience, I do not know how to do it.

If anyone has any ideas, I will be glad to help)

thank you

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {
        static final String[] CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION = new String[] {
                Contacts._ID,  
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, 
                Contacts.STARRED,  
                Contacts.TIMES_CONTACTED,  
                Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE,  
                Contacts.PHOTO_ID,  
                Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,  
                Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER                  
        };

        static final int SUMMARY_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;
        static final int SUMMARY_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;
        static final int SUMMARY_STARRED_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;
        static final int SUMMARY_TIMES_CONTACTED_COLUMN_INDEX = 3;
        static final int SUMMARY_PRESENCE_STATUS_COLUMN_INDEX = 4;
        static final int SUMMARY_PHOTO_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 5;
        static final int SUMMARY_LOOKUP_KEY = 6;
        static final int SUMMARY_HAS_PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX = 7;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";
        Cursor c =
                getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select,
                null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        startManagingCursor(c);

        ContactListItemAdapter adapter = new ContactListItemAdapter(this, R.layout.main, c);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private final class ContactListItemAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
        public ContactListItemAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
            super(context, layout, c);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            final ContactListItemCache cache = (ContactListItemCache) view.getTag();

            cursor.copyStringToBuffer(SUMMARY_NAME_COLUMN_INDEX, cache.nameBuffer);
            int size = cache.nameBuffer.sizeCopied;

            cursor.copyStringToBuffer(SUMMARY_HAS_PHONE_COLUMN_INDEX, cache.numberView);
            int number = cache.numberView.sizeCopied;

            cache.nameView.setText(cache.nameBuffer.data, 0, size);
            cache.numView.setText(cache.numberView.data, 0, number);
            final long contactId = cursor.getLong(SUMMARY_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
            final String lookupKey = cursor.getString(SUMMARY_LOOKUP_KEY);
            cache.photoView.assignContactUri(Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey));

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
            ContactListItemCache cache = new ContactListItemCache();
            cache.nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            cache.numView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);
            cache.photoView = (QuickContactBadge) view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
            view.setTag(cache);

            return view;
        }
    }

    final static class ContactListItemCache {
        public TextView nameView;
        public TextView numView;
        public CharArrayBuffer numberView = new CharArrayBuffer(128);
        public QuickContactBadge photoView;
        public CharArrayBuffer nameBuffer = new CharArrayBuffer(128);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is completely right. I suggest you narrow down your selection to :

```
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=" + 1;
```

and see what results you're getting. After that add the other constraints.